# Replacing class reference from "built-in" assembly with out-of-band assembly using Visual Studio 2019 Preview for Mac

Tags: .net, xamarin, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-2019

*Background:* I'm currently trying to use EF6 to connect to a MySQL database and am searching for a resolution to [an error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875956/exception-when-trying-to-use-mysql-data-entity) about a type [not being able to be loaded from an assembly](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16101). I believe I've found a possible solution, using an [out-of-band release of a different assembly that includes the class](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/33788#issuecomment-449170643), but that solution has yielded yet another question that seems to be distinct enough from the first to be its own question (even though answering one question may answer both).

*Question:* How can I include an out-of-band assembly using Visual Studio 2019 Preview for Mac in a way that lets me use a specific class from the assembly? I'd like to use the [3.0 preview release](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/33788#issuecomment-449170643) of `System.Component.Annotations` to get at the [`AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.associatedmetadatatypetypedescriptionprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) class required by EF. When I try to follow the [instructions for adding an OOB assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/the-net-framework-and-out-of-band-releases) and rebuild my project, an exception gets thrown indicating that the old version of a different assembly that seems to also include that class.

Package Console Output:

```
Successfully installed 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.6.0-preview.18571.3' to Ef2MySql
```

Exception:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider' from assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

***edit:*** I just checked that `AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider` is in the NuGet package by running `nuget install System.ComponentModel.Annotations -Version 4.6.0-preview.19073.11` in an unrelated, empty directory and them opening `System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.6.0-preview.19073.11/lib/net461/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll` with VS. *However, it's not in all of the DLLs in the NuGet package. Just the one in `net461`.*

***further edit:*** However, adding the assembly that I verified has the class as an .NET assembly (rather than using NuGet in VS) still does not resolve the error.

[image: Screenshot showing class in assembly]

Comment: I created a new project and installed `System.ComponentModel.Annotations 4.6.0-preview.19073.11` and installed latest `EntityFramework`, rebuild my project and did not get any errors. Is there any other thing I need to do to reproduce your problem? What's the different assembly that seems to also include that class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @JackHua-MSFT. The error is an exception; I edited the question to clarify that. The two assemblies listed on Microsoft's documentation for the AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider class in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace are System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll and System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll.

Comment: I just did a little checking with the nuget command and found that the class isn't in all of the version of the assembly in the nuget package.

Comment: You'd better report to Microsoft directly, https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues

Answer (score 0):

### ## Consider using sqlite instead ##

Microsoft RazorPagesMovie tutorial using **sqlite** instead of **mysql** in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac:

---

(Try to modify it to include your issue, and hopefully you may learn from it enough to help you resolve your issues with mysql)

1. Follow [Tutorial: Get started with Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac)
2. And the second part: [Add a model to a Razor Pages app in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac)